# Error using std::find with operator==

Tags: c++, std

I am getting an error using std::find on the following structure ...

```
struct ComplianceOrderRecord {
    explicit ComplianceOrderRecord(IOrder& order);
    bool operator ==(const ComplianceOrderRecord& other) const;
    double price;
};

inline bool ComplianceOrderRecord::operator ==(const ComplianceOrderRecord& other) const {
    return price == other.price;
}
```

I use it as follows...

```
inline void Compliance::RemoveComplianceOrderRecord(const ComplianceOrderRecord& order) {
    auto it = std::find(m_compliantOrderList.begin(),
    m_compliantOrderList.end(), order);
    if(it == m_compliantOrderList.end()) {
        return;
    }
    m_compliantOrderList.erase(it);
}
```

The error is...

```
error C2679: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const ComplianceOrderRecord' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Any help in understanding this error would be very appreciated.

Comment: After updating this to `const` I get the same result.

Comment: Show us the declaration of `m_compliantOrderList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be reproduced if `m_compliantOrderList` is not a `container<ComplianceOrderRecord >`. (Perhaps it is a container of **pointers**, or some other completely unrelated class.

---

Edit:

Your equality operator can compare two instances of `ComplianceOrderRecord`, but `find` needs to compare a pointer against an object. Overloading an operator to perform this kind of comparison would be bizarre, so you could use `find_if` with a custom predicate, such as:

```
   struct RecordIsEqualTo
   {
      const ComplianceOrderRecord* record;
      RecordIsEqualTo(const ComplianceOrderRecord& r): record(&r) {}
      bool operator() (const ComplianceOrderRecord* r) const { return *record == *r; }
   };

   std::find_if(m_compliantOrderList.begin(), m_compliantOrderList.end(),
      RecordIsEqualTo(order) );
```

or a lambda version thereof.

Comment: The contained is defined as `std::list<ComplianceOrderRecord*> m_compliantOrderList;`

Answer (score 5):

Your `operator==` should be a `const` member, or even better, a freestanding function.

Comment: Good point about the freestanding function, since his class supports implicit conversions.  As a member, `aComplianceOrderRecord == anIOrder` is legal, but `anIOrder == aComplianceOrderRecord` isn't.  (Generally, I'd make the constructor `explicit`, to remove the implicit conversion, but I don't know whether it is wanted here or not.)

Comment: Good catch, I made the constructor explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator==` function should be `const`.  As it is, you can't call it on a `const` object (or a reference to `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Try a const method:

```
inline bool ComplianceOrderRecord::operator ==(const ComplianceOrderRecord& other) const {
return price == other.price;
```

}

Comment: Adding `const` does not resolve the issue for me unfortunately.